# Julia: docstrings and LaTeX

Tags: julia

Julia has `docstrings` capabilities, which are documented here https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/documentation/. I'm under the impression that it has support for `LaTeX` code, but I'm not sure if the intention is that the LaTeX code should look like code or like an interpretation. In the following, the LaTeX code is garbled somewhat (see rho, for instance) and not interpreted (rho does not look like ρ). Am I doing something wrong?

**Is there a way to get `LaTeX` code look interpreted?**

What I mean by interpreted is something like what they do at https://math.stackexchange.com/.

The documentation says that `LaTeX` code should be wrapped around double back-quotes and that Greek letters should be typed as `ρ` rather than `\rho`. But that rather defeats the point of being able to include `LaTeX` code, doesn't it?

Note: Version 0.5.2 run in Juno/Atom console.

```
"""

Module blabla

The objective function is:
``\max \mathbb{E}_0 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\rho t} F(x_t) dt``

"""
module blabla
end
```

If I then execute the module and query I get this:

[image]

With triple quotes, the dollar signs disappear, but the formula is printed on a dark background:

[image]

**EDIT** Follow-up to David P. Sanders' suggestion to use the `Documenter.jl` package.

```
    using Documenter
    doc"""
    Module blabla

    The objective function is:
    $\max \mathbb{E}_0 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\rho t} F(x_t) dt$
    """
    module blabla
    end
```

Gives the following: the `LaTeX` code appears to print correctly, but it's not interpreted (ρ is displayed as `\rho`. I followed suggestions in: https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/latex.html to

[image]

Comment: Does using double backticks work? That was my impression.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski, thanks for your interest. I have edited the question to clarify the difference between double-quotes and triple-quotes.

Comment: I think the issue is just that Juno/Atom doesn't support rendering LaTeX.  Edit: see https://github.com/JunoLab/atom-julia-client/issues/329.

Comment: @MattB., thanks you were right. I did not understand that issue 329 when I clicked on it: abstruse for me. What IDE would support ``Julia`` and ``LaTeX`` docstrings? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rendering LaTeX code as actual equations has to be supported by whichever software renders your docstrings. So, the short answer to why you're not seeing any rendered equations in Juno is that LaTeX rendering is currently not supported in Juno (as Matt B. pointed out, there's an [open issue for that](https://github.com/JunoLab/atom-julia-client/issues/329)).

**The `doc""` string literal / string macro is there to get around another issue.** Backslashes and dollar signs normally have a special meaning in string literals -- [escape sequences](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/strings#man-characters-1) and [variable interpolation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/strings#string-interpolation-1), respectively (e.g. `\n` gets replaced by a newline character, `$(variable)` inserts the value of `variable` into the string). This, of course, clashes with the ordinary LaTeX commands and delimiters (e.g. `\frac`, `$...$`). So, to actually have backslashes and dollar signs in a string you need to escape them all with backslashes, e.g.:

```
julia> "\$\\frac{x}{y}\$" |> print
$\frac{x}{y}$
```

Not doing that will either give an error:

```
julia> "$\frac{x}{y}$" |> print
ERROR: syntax: invalid interpolation syntax: "$\"
```

or invalid characters in the resulting strings:

```
julia> "``\e^x``" |> print
``^x``
```

Having to escape everything all the time would, of course, be annoying when writing docstrings. So, to get around this, as David pointed out out, you can use the `doc` string macro / non-standard string literal. In a `doc` literal all standard escape sequences are ignored, so an unescaped LaTeX string doesn't cause any issues:

```
julia> doc"$\frac{x}{y}$" |> print
$$
\frac{x}{y}
$$
```

*Note: `doc` also parses the Markdown in the string and actually returns a `Base.Markdown.MD` object, not a string, which is why the printed string is a bit different from the input.*

Finally, you can then use these `doc`-literals as normal docstrings, but you can then freely use LaTeX syntax without having to worry about escaping everything:

```
doc"""
$\frac{x}{y}$
"""
function foo end
```

This is also documented in [Documenter's manual](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/latest/man/latex/#Escaping-characters-in-docstrings-1), although it is not actually specific to Documenter.

**Double backticks vs dollar signs.** The preferred way to mark LaTeX in Julia docstrings or documentation is by using [double backticks](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/documentation#%5C%5CLaTeX-1) or [```` ```math ```` blocks](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/documentation#Display-equations-1), as documented in the manual. Dollar signs are supported for backwards compatibility.

*Note: Documenter's manual and the `show` methods for Markdown objects in Julia should be updated to reflect this.*

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer! I do have a follow-up question and a comment. ``1.`` If the ``Julia`` console and ``Juno`` IDE do not support displaying ``LaTeX`` docstrings as ``math``, then what IDE should I use to get the benefit of the ``Documenter.jl`` package?  ``2.`` I do hope that dollar signs keep getting supported, as there is a huge benefit in being able to copy-paste equation chunks from a ``LaTeX`` article to ``Julia`` docstrings, without having to retype the whole thing. I'm looking at huge matrices and arrays. Long live the dollar!

Comment: Depends on what you mean exactly: if you want equations in an IDE, then [IJulia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl) (the Julia kernel for [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/)) will do that, but the IDE has a very different philosophy compared to Juno. But just to clarify, Documenter is irrelevant here -- Documenter's only purpose is to generate HTML pages [like these](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/latest/), independent of an IDE.

Comment: As for backticks vs dollar signs -- there are good reasons to prefer backticks in Markdown. And you only have to change to delimiters, the rest of the equation can be copied without issues. There should be some discussion on both the Commonmark discourse forum and in some Julia or Documenter PRs about this, although I couldn't find the references right away.

Comment: Didn't know that backticks were now the recommended solution, thanks. It's kind of unfortunate if you're so used to writing latex notation. I guess that doesn't work in markdown in the jupyter notebook?

Comment: Thanks mortenpi for these clarifications. The first few paragraphs of this page (https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/latest/) do not explicitly mention that ``Documenter`` is for creating ``html`` pages, but instead refers to the ``Julia`` documentation doc page, creating confusion about Documenter's true purpose. I can see that ``IJulia`` is attractive for blogging, teaching, tutorials, but if you have a scientific article written in ``LaTeX`` and ``Julia`` code for replication, it's redundant imho, esp. if you need to retype all the backtips. Anyways, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders Nope, Jupyter uses only dollars as far as I know. I think originally Mike H. got the idea for backticks from [Scholarly Markdown](http://scholarlymarkdown.com/Scholarly-Markdown-Guide.html#math). The problem with $ signs in Markdown is that it has other well-established meanings which clash. There's more discussion [on the corresponding CommonMark thread](https://talk.commonmark.org/t/mathjax-extension-for-latex-equations/698).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
doc"""
    ...
"""
```

This is a "non-standard string literal" used by the `Documenter.jl` package; see https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/strings/#non-standard-string-literals.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question with an example of my attempt to use ``Documenter.jl``. I don't see the interpreted equation that the manual has. I'm using ``Atom``, could that be a problem? Do I need to install additional packages? Thanks!

Comment: With doc""" you just use standard latex notation inside, with $

Comment: Thanks David. So I changed the double quotes with a dollar sign in the code above and got the exact same output you can see in the third image. Any ideas? Thanks.